# Using ActiveRecord to search through an object's associations and return instances where all of the associations do/do not contain a certain value

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, associations

I'm attempting to query an object's associations, and only return objects where all of their associations are of a certain value. For example, if a **User** has a **memberships** association, and memberships has an **active(boolean)** field, I want to return a collection of all users that only have memberships with **active: false**.

The query I'm working with right now is:

```
User.includes(:memberships).where(memberships: {active: false})
```

However, this gives me all users that have inactive memberships, but also all users that have both **active: false** and **active: true** memberships. I tried doing an extra .where.not on this, but of course, that returned the same group.

I've considered mapping over the collection of users and creating a new array, kicking out the users with active memberships, but I need to keep the final value as an AR Collection as I continue to query it further in the controller.

I would prefer to stick to using ActiveRecord for this, but if it's not doable and I need to use SQL instead, I'm also open to that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple things here - you want a LEFT OUTTER joins, so make sure your SQL query is being constructed properly. Check with

```
User.includes(:memberships).where(memberships: {active: false}).explain
```

or

```
User.includes(:memberships).where(memberships: {active: false}).to_sql
```

Second, try:

```
User.joins(:memberships).where("memberships.active = ?", false)
```

or perhaps give `.merge` a try, which I like to use:

```
User.joins(:memberships).merge(Membership.inactive)
```

assuming you have a scope/class method `.inactive` on the `Membership` model

```
def self.inactive
  where(active: false)
end
```

`.includes` should really only be used if you need the relationship loaded into memory.

#### EDIT:

Easiest way to exclude any user that has a single (of many) memberships would be to split this up into 2 queries.

```
active_user_ids = Membership.active.pluck(:user_id).uniq
User.where("id NOT IN (?)", active_user_ids.join(","))
```

Comment: Thanks! I've confirmed that I'm using Left Outer Joins using .explain, and also tried the joins method. I'm running in to the same issue though. If a user has both an Active and an Inactive membership, they'll still be returned.

Comment: @swats - I updated my answer. To stay in AR, and not drop down into a nasty SQL statement, just split up the query. This is still pretty performant barring you don't have millions of users (joining that string could be expensive).

Answer (score 0):

To exclude Users with both a valid and invalid membership try--

`User.includes(:memberships).where(memberships: {active: false}).where.not(memberships: {active: true})`

Also--you probably want to use #joins instead of #includes.  If you don't need access to the Memberships except for the query, there is no need to load that into memory (which #include does).

This article has a nice explanation--
http://tomdallimore.com/blog/includes-vs-joins-in-rails-when-and-where/